# NSURLConnection with the custom SSL validation

Tags: ios, ssl, nsurlconnection

I have a question about an extended SSL certificate verification on iOS. The code I have looks as it follows:

```
- (void) validateAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

    if (!someCustomCheck()) { // I do some custom check here
        [paramChallenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:[challenge protectionSpace].serverTrust];
    if (credential) {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
    else {
        [challenge.sender cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

The tests show me that at this point the normal iOS check for SSL certificate is not happening. Can I assume that if I replace the line:

```
[challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

with

```
[challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

so after my custom check I will still have the default system SSL certificate check?

It makes sense from the documentation but many examples which I have seen normally do some custom verification and then call

```
[challenge.sender useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

Thanks.